# How do I convert a list which is a list?

Tags: python, list

Suppose there is a list which looks like this

```
genre = '[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}]'
```

When I checked type of this variable it showed string.
I used

```
genre = genre.strip('][').split(', ')
```

but it became this

```
['{"id": 28', '"name": "Action"}', '{"id": 12', '"name": "Adventure"}']
```

as you can see the contents inside the list are still strings. I want them to be dictionaries

Comment: It's JSON, use `json.loads()`

Answer (score 2):

Barmar's comment answers it. This is what you need:

```
import json
genre = '[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}]'
genre = json.loads(genre)
```

You can then access the dictionary elements with a loop:

```
for item in genre:
    id = item['id']
    name = item['name']
```